# How to add 300 to a variable on each iteration using a for loop in php?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop, addition

I am  trying to make a loop that iterates 6 times, on each iteration I want to add 300 to the variable $count.

```
 $count = 300;
 for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) { 
     $count + 300;
     echo $count; //300300300300300300
 }
```

The results I wanted to achieve are

```
echo $count // 300600900120018002400
```

How can I acheive these results?

Comment: Please read any tutorial on basically any programming language and you will understand it.

Comment: `echo $count + 300 ."<br/>";` need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, assign value to $count. **$count = $count + 300;**

```
<?php
 $sum_number = 300;
 $count = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) { 
     $count = $count + $sum_number;
     echo $count."\n"; 
 }
?>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/674532)**

Comment: Perfect, I wonder why the code I used didn't do what I thought it would?

Comment: @FabianAmran because you didn't assign the new value to the count variable

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $count = $count + 300;
        echo $count; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this

```
<?php
 $count = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) { 
     $count= $count+ 300;
     echo $count; //300600900120015001800
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 7 ; $i++) { 
      if($i){
       $count .= ($i+1) * 300;
       }else{
       $count = 300;
       } 
   }
  echo $count; // 30060090012001500180021002400
```

Comment: may i know the reason of downvoting

Comment: A novel approach, but I *think* OP is looking for an *arithmetic* operation.

Comment: I would recommend this answer also. Wondering why there is a downvote?

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, you have to loop again the count, try this:

```
 for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) { 
     if($i == 0) {
        $count = 300;
     } else {
        $count = $count + 300;
     }
     echo $count;

 }
```

Comment: Down voting for the given problem and answering the right way based on the given question?

Comment: What's with the (highly unnecessary) if-else?!

Comment: @Biffen What if the OP have a reason on defaulting the value of $count to 300? The if-else is when the looping starts if the $i starts with 0 it should first start printing 300 then else will add 300?

Comment: If ifs and buts, etc. OP quite clearly initialises it just before the loop.